# NSTimer calculate hours

Tags: iphone, nstimer, nsnumber

I am using an NSTimer which I have working to show minutes and seconds.  But I am confused about the math needed to calculate hours.

I am using:

```
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    static int count = 0;
    count += 1;
    int seconds = count % 60;
    int minutes = (count - seconds) / 60;
    // Not sure how to calculate hours
    int hours = (count - minutes) / 60;
    self.timer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2d", hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

What calculation should I use for hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
seconds = ...
seconds_in_minute = seconds % 60;
minutes_in_hour = ( seconds / 60 ) % 60;
hour_in_day = ( seconds / 3600 ) % 24;
```